# Generic function for subset of properties using Pick

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to implement a generic function for a subset of properties of another model, in order to be able to use smaller types, using **Pick** utility type.

However I get an error that the constraint is not satisfied.

Here is a sample:

```
export class BigModel {
   public prop1: string = '';
   public prop2: number = 0;
   public prop3: boolean = true;
}

export type SubsetModel = Pick<BigModel, 'prop1' | 'prop2'>;

export function genericFunction<TSubsetModel extends Pick<BigModel, keyof BigModel>>(data: TSubsetModel): void {
   // do something
}

const newObj: SubsetModel = { prop1: 'test', prop2: 1 };

genericFunction<SubsetModel>(newObj);
// Type 'SubsetModel' does not satisfy the constraint 'Pick<BigModel, keyof BigModel>'.
//  Property 'prop3' is missing in type 'SubsetModel' but required in type 'Pick<BigModel, keyof BigModel>'.(2344)
//input.tsx(4, 11): 'prop3' is declared here.
```

The same happens in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

Any ideas?

Comment: The constraint `Pick<BigModel, keyof BigModel` is equivalent to `BigModel`, because you are picking all keys. Maybe what you want is `Partial<BigModel>`? It depends on your use case

Comment: Nope, because Partial makes the properties optional, I don't want to loose their type. Also, how is it equivalent to BigModel? Pick states `From T, pick a set of properties whose keys are in the union K`

Comment: It's equivalent because `keyof BigModel` is equal to `'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3'`, so then you end up doing `Pick<BigModel, 'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3'>`, which is the same as `BigModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @bugs in the comments, `extends Pick<BigModel, keyof BigModel>` requires that `TSubsetModel` has all of the properties of `BigModel`.  `keyof BigModel` includes all of the keys in `BigModel` so  `Pick<BigModel, keyof BigModel>` is just `BigModel`.  In order to extend that, you need to have a complete `BigModel` and possibly some extra properties.

What you want is for your generic to **depend on the keys**. `K extends keyof BigModel` will be some subset of the keys.

```
export function genericFunction<K extends keyof BigModel>(data: Pick<BigModel, K>): void {
   // do something
}
```

When you call `genericFunction` with a `SubsetModel`:

```
const newObj: SubsetModel = { prop1: 'test', prop2: 1 };

genericFunction(newObj);
```

It resolves to this:

```
function genericFunction<"prop1" | "prop2">(data: Pick<BigModel, "prop1" | "prop2">): void
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WP59qw)